# Update a cell on change with a date for a number of cells in a worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a worksheet with a column for each month.  Each cell is updated via other worksheets but I want a date added automatically to the cell as to when that happens.  I tried code to do that but it changes the dates to the same for the entire column. What did I miss?  How can I get it to only change the date for the cell that changes on that day.  For instance, over a ten day period, dozens of users update cells in that column.  I don't want the dates the same.

Here is what I used?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim targetRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Integer

Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("H:H"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("J:J"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("L:L"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("P:P"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("R:R"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("T:T"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("V:V"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("X:X"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("Z:Z"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("AB:AB"), Target)
Set targetRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("AD:AD"), Target)

c = 1

If Not targetRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each rng In targetRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
          rng.Offset(0, c).Value = Now
          rng.Offset(0, c).NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
        Else
       rng.Offset(0, c).ClearContents
       End If

    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: the last **Set targetRng** overrides all the others.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want to do that's better?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064439/detect-whether-cell-value-was-actually-changed-by-editing) out

Answer (score 0):

**You are facing the problem because, you have occupied Column H to AD entirely to get the data from other Sheet but not specified where the Current Date and Time will be inserted.**

Suppose the incoming data occupies H1:AD1 then the Current Date should be entered in the adjacent Column AE1 and for this **OffsetColumn** script is required to be included in place of the **variable C**, you have used with.

*Below is a sample code will help you, how to use the xOffsetColumn.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("H:H"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each Rng In WorkRng

        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

**NB: I've used only one Column is H, you need to include all the required Columns.**

*I do hope this help you.*